# Configuration usage inside an Entity class

Tags: c#

Imagine, we have an entity like this:

```
public class Entity
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<int, string> Data { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<int, string> RestirctedData
            {           
                get 
                {
                    int restiriction = 5;
                    //how to do it the way not to be hardcode but "injected" from config?        
                    return Data.Where(d => d.Key < restiriction).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Repositories (more than one in different projects) are reading data from database and instantiate that entity. Later entity is getting used in services classes (also different projects).
Goal is to limit data reading from Data collection, but to limit it in one place. Ideally in getter. I don't want to have it hardcoded, ideally, limit should come from configuration. How would you do that? Thanks.

Comment: Such a logic shouldn't be an entity but in something else creating and handling out the entity.  You should strive for having NO dependencies in things you call entity,poco, record or whatever that should hold just data.

Comment: I agree with that. That's why i am trying to look at the thing widely. Conditions: 1) All is about existing projects. It contains dozen repositories (read from DB, produces entities) 2) There are 20< services doing something with that entitles. So, options: 1) Rework repositories (restrict data when reading) 2) Rework services (filter data in it). Both requires a lot of refactoring. Looking for some magic idea how to do it in one place )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking of injection, I assume you're using .NET Core, right?

You'd better be injecting your configuration file in the `Entity` class constructor:

```
public class Entity 
{ 
     IConfiguration Configuration;
     int restriction;
     public Dictionary<int, string> Data { get; set; }

     public Entity(IConfiguration config)
     {
         Configuration = config;
         restriction = Configuration["restriction"];
     }

     public Dictionary<int, string> RestrictedData
     {           
         get 
         {
             return Data.Where(e => yourConditions).Take(restriction);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. But it doesn't look efficient if we need to read from db and map hundred thousands records. "injected" meaning was about how to get that limit inside getter (not primarily in DI sense)

Comment: @G.B. performance in dependancy injection isn't affected by number of record, since the reading of the configuration is done before you get the records... I have modified the query to actually take that into consideration. If you use `IQueryable<T>` instead of `Dictionary<T,K>`, actual execution is defered

Answer (score 1):

ideally the logic shouldn't be there but if you want to do that then you can have a property which reads the data from configuration

```
    public int Restriction 
    {
        get
        {
            return Configuration.GetValue<int>("Restriction");
        }
    }
```

then you use this property to restrict number of records.

Comment: I think you should change the prop signature from `string` to `int`?